# Remove raster pixel in R

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing, ndvi

This is the 32 year trend NDVI (raster data)

I would like to remove the green grids data by using R (the green pixel value is larger than 0.03) 
[image: NDVI trend]

and this one is R code that i use but i cannot remove it ...

[image: R code]

Could anyone please suggest me what should I do ?

regards,
faris

Answer (score 3):

Ok I use this

NDVI.slope[NDVI.slope>0.03] <- NA

In stead of

NDVI.slope_2<-trim((NDVI.slope), padding=0, values = c(0.02:0.03))

................ and It work !!!!! ...................

Comment: This is exactly the recommendation that I would have given. However, keep in mind that when you use a bracket index on a raster class object it is read into memory thus, negating the advantage of holding rasters out of memory. Using the functions for reclassifying data, provided by the raster package, will keep problems memory safe.